# How can I measure on-save action performance per file in Typescript project in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am working in a typescript codebase that is suffering from some serious performance issues when it comes to developer experience. Most notably, it can take in upwards of 10 seconds to save certain files. We have been able to deduce that there are certain types and functions that seem to have an outsized impact on performance here but we're looking for a way to measure the time to perform on-save actions per file so we can be sure that the changes we're trying to make are having a meaningful impact.

I have looked at trying to use the typescript library to at least get type evaluation performance but seem to not be getting anything meaningful from `getPreEmitDiagnostics`. Otherwise I've looked at the documentation that I can find on `tsc` and `vs-code` cli tools to little avail.

Answer (score 0):

See [microsoft/TypeScript-Wiki > Performance](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance). It has suggestions for common code patterns and structural issues that can cause performance problems. It also has a few good sections for debugging those issues:

- *[Performance Tracing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#performance-tracing)*: `tsc -p ./some/project/src/tsconfig.json --generateTrace tracing_output_folder` - which can then be viewed in trace viewers such as [`@typescript/analyze-trace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript/analyze-trace) and Chrome/Chromium's `chrome://tracing`
- *[Profiling the Compiler](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#profiling-the-compiler)*: if the performance tracing doesn't work out, using `node --trace-ic ./node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js --generateCpuProfile profile.cpuprofile`

Most of the time, just the *Performance Tracing* section is enough to find key hotspots in code.

Comment: Those docs are really helpful, though I was hoping to come up with a way to output some per-file metrics so we could evaluate the impact of some of those changes. The problem I think is that we are dealing with many different issues in different ways across our codebase so seeing how migrating a union to the base types, for example, impacts perf across the codebase.